# I want to send an automated message on LinkedIn using vanilla JavaScript but it does not work

Tags: javascript, linkedin-api, messagebox, browser-automation

I am using a program that do all as expetected untill it has to insert the Message Text inside of the TextBox.

After that it works properly, pressing the send button and doing all the rest of operations.

The problem is in the PasteNote function.

```
 

Linkedin = {
    config: {
        scrollDelay: 2000,
        actionDelay: 3000,
        nextPageDelay: 5000,
        // set to -1 for no limit
        maxRequests: -1,
        totalRequestsSent: 0,
        // set to false to skip adding note in invites
        // addNote: true,
        note: "Dear {{name}}, thank you for sharing your professional network."
    },
    //The init function is called when the script is initialized.
    //and it sets a delay before calling the scrollBottom function. 
    init: function (data, config) {
        console.info("INFO: script initialized on the page...");
        console.debug("DEBUG: scrolling to bottom in " + config.scrollDelay + " ms");
        setTimeout(() => this.scrollBottom(data, config), config.actionDelay);
    },
    //The scrollBottom function uses the scrollTo method to smoothly scroll the page to the bottom. 
    //After a delay, it calls the scrollTop function.
    scrollBottom: function (data, config) {
        window.scrollTo({ top: document.body.scrollHeight, behavior: 'smooth' });
        console.debug("DEBUG: scrolling to top in " + config.scrollDelay + " ms");
        setTimeout(() => this.scrollTop(data, config), config.scrollDelay);
    },
    //The scrollTop function, scrolls the page back to the top.
    scrollTop: function (data, config) {
        window.scrollTo({ top: 0, behavior: 'smooth' });
        console.debug("DEBUG: inspecting elements in " + config.scrollDelay + " ms");
        //The scrollTop function then sets a delay before calling the inspect function
        setTimeout(() => this.inspect(data, config), config.scrollDelay);
    },
    //The inspect function looks for elements on the page with the text "Message" 
    //and stores them in an array called pageButtons.
    inspect: function (data, config) {
        var totalRows = this.totalRows();
        console.debug("DEBUG: total search results found on page are " + totalRows);
        if (totalRows >= 0) {
            this.compile(data, config);
        } else {
            console.warn("WARN: end of search results!");
            this.complete(config);
        }
    },
    compile: function (data, config) {
        var elements = document.querySelectorAll('button');
        data.pageButtons = [...elements].filter(function (element) {
            return element.textContent.trim() === "Message";
        });
        //If this array (pageButtons) is empty, the script moves to the next page by calling the nextPage function. 
        //If the array is not empty, the script begins sending messages by calling the sendMessages function.
        if (!data.pageButtons || data.pageButtons.length === 0) {
            console.warn("ERROR: no message buttons found on page!");
            console.info("INFO: moving to next page...");
            setTimeout(() => { this.nextPage(config) }, config.nextPageDelay);
        } else {
            data.pageButtonTotal = data.pageButtons.length;
            console.info("INFO: " + data.pageButtonTotal + " message buttons found");
            data.pageButtonIndex = 0;
            var names = document.getElementsByClassName("entity-result__title-text");
            names = [...names].filter(function (element) {
                return element.parentNode.parentNode.parentNode.parentNode.parentNode.parentNode.parentNode.parentNode.textContent.includes("Message\n");
            });
            data.connectNames = [...names].map(function (element) {
                return element.innerText.split(" ")[0];
            });
            console.debug("DEBUG: starting to send messages in " + config.actionDelay + " ms");
            setTimeout(() => { this.sendMessages(data, config) }, config.actionDelay);
        }
    },
    //The sendMessages function clicks the button at the current index of the pageButtons array, 
    sendMessages: function (data, config) {
        console.debug("remaining requests " + config.maxRequests);
        if (config.maxRequests == 0) {
            console.info("INFO: max requests reached for the script run!");
            this.complete(config);
        } else {
            console.debug('DEBUG: sending invite to ' + (data.pageButtonIndex + 1) + ' out of ' + data.pageButtonTotal);
            var button = data.pageButtons[data.pageButtonIndex];
            button.click();
            //and if the addNote configuration is set to true, it adds a note to the invite using the clickAddNote function.
            // clicking Add a note in popup, if present
            console.debug("DEBUG: pasting Message in popup, in " + config.actionDelay + " ms");
            setTimeout(() => this.pasteNote(data, config), config.actionDelay);

            // clicking done in popup, if present
            // console.debug("DEBUG: clicking done in popup, in " + config.actionDelay + " ms");
            // setTimeout(() => this.clickDone(data, config), config.actionDelay);

    }},
   
    //The addNote function adds the specified note to the invite by replacing the string "{{name}}" 
    //with the name of the recipient and then setting the value of the text area to the modified note. 
    //It then clicks the "Send" button to send the invite.

    pasteNote: function (data, config) {
        console.log("start of pasteNote" + noteTextBox);
        //noteTextBox = document.getElementByClass("msg-form__msg-content-container");
        // we select the space where we want to insert the note
        noteTextBox = document.querySelector("[class^='msg-form__msg-content-container--scrollable']");
        console.log(noteTextBox.value);
        noteTextBox.value = config.note.replace("{{name}}", data.connectNames[data.pageButtonIndex]);
        noteTextBox.dispatchEvent(new Event('input', {
            bubbles: true
        }));
        window.onload = noteTextBox.value;
        console.log("end of pasteNote" + noteTextBox.value);

        console.debug("DEBUG: clicking send in popup, if present, in " + config.actionDelay + " ms");
        setTimeout(() => this.clickDone(data, config), config.actionDelay);
    },
    clickDone: function (data, config) {
        var buttons = document.querySelectorAll('button');
        var doneButton = Array.prototype.filter.call(buttons, function (el) {
            return el.textContent.trim() === 'Send';
        });
        // Click the first send button
        if (doneButton && doneButton[0]) {
            console.debug("DEBUG: clicking send button to close popup");
            doneButton[0].click();
        } else {
            console.debug("DEBUG: send button not found, clicking close on the popup in " + config.actionDelay);
        }
        setTimeout(() => this.clickClose(data, config), config.actionDelay);
    },
    clickClose: function (data, config) {
        var closeButton = document.getElementsByClassName('artdeco-modal__dismiss artdeco-button artdeco-button--circle artdeco-button--muted artdeco-button--2 artdeco-button--tertiary ember-view');
        if (closeButton && closeButton[0]) {
            closeButton[0].click();
        }
        console.info('INFO: invite sent to ' + (data.pageButtonIndex + 1) + ' out of ' + data.pageButtonTotal);
        config.maxRequests--;
        config.totalRequestsSent++;
        //After sending the invite, the function increments the pageButtonIndex and checks 
        //if it is less than the total number of buttons. 
        //If it is, the function calls itself again with the updated pageButtonIndex.
        //If not, it calls the complete function.
        if (data.pageButtonIndex === (data.pageButtonTotal - 1)) {
            console.debug("DEBUG: all connections for the page done, going to next page in " + config.actionDelay + " ms");
            setTimeout(() => this.nextPage(config), config.actionDelay);
        } else {
            data.pageButtonIndex++;
            console.debug("DEBUG: sending next invite in " + config.actionDelay + " ms");
            setTimeout(() => this.sendMessages(data, config), config.actionDelay);
        }
    },

    nextPage: function (config) {
        var pagerButton = document.getElementsByClassName('artdeco-pagination__button--next');
        if (!pagerButton || pagerButton.length === 0 || pagerButton[0].hasAttribute('disabled')) {
            console.info("INFO: no next page button found!");
            return this.complete(config);
        }
        console.info("INFO: Going to next page...");
        pagerButton[0].children[0].click();
        setTimeout(() => this.init({}, config), config.nextPageDelay);
    },
    //Finally, the complete function is called when the script has finished running 
    //or when the maximum number of requests has been reached. 
    //It logs a message to the console indicating that the script has completed.
    complete: function (config) {
        console.info('INFO: script completed after sending ' + config.totalRequestsSent + ' messages');
    },
    totalRows: function () {
        var search_results = document.getElementsByClassName('search-result');
        if (search_results && search_results.length != 0) {
            return search_results.length;
        } else {
            return 0;
        }
    }
}

Linkedin.init({}, Linkedin.config);
```

It follows the output from the console

```
NFO: script initialized on the page... debugger eval code:18:17
DEBUG: scrolling to bottom in 2000 ms debugger eval code:19:17
undefined
DEBUG: scrolling to top in 2000 ms debugger eval code:26:17
DEBUG: inspecting elements in 2000 ms debugger eval code:32:17
DEBUG: total search results found on page are 0 debugger eval code:40:17
INFO: 1 message buttons found debugger eval code:61:21
DEBUG: starting to send messages in 3000 ms debugger eval code:70:21
remaining requests -1 debugger eval code:76:17
DEBUG: sending invite to 1 out of 1 debugger eval code:81:21
DEBUG: pasting Message in popup, in 3000 ms debugger eval code:86:21
start of pasteNote[object HTMLDivElement] debugger eval code:100:17
undefined debugger eval code:104:17
end of pasteNote Dear Valerio, I'm Valerio, thank you for sharing your professional network. debugger eval code:110:17
DEBUG: clicking send in popup, if present, in 3000 ms debugger eval code:112:17
DEBUG: clicking send button to close popup debugger eval code:122:21
INFO: invite sent to 1 out of 1 debugger eval code:134:17
DEBUG: all connections for the page done, going to next page in 3000 ms debugger eval code:142:21
INFO: no next page button found! debugger eval code:154:21
INFO: script completed after sending 1 messages debugger eval code:165:17
```

I try to change the querySelector. Also the console log value is the expected but it does not appear in the textbox.

Answer (score 0):

```js
var el_msg_form = document.getElementsByClassName("msg-form__contenteditable")[0]; 
var el_name = document.getElementsByClassName("profile-card-one-to-one__profile-link")[0];
var el_placeholder = document.getElementsByClassName("msg-form__placeholder")[0];
var first_name = el_name.innerHTML.trim().split(" ")[0];
var greeting = "Hi " + first_name + ",\n\n";
document.execCommand('insertText', false, greeting);
el_msg_form.focus();
el_placeholder.remove();
document.close();
```

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer such that others can learn from it